# React Context, how to update context in one branch, to use in another branch

Tags: reactjs, react-context

Can I use the React Context API to manage the global state for `itemsInCart`, allowing `Product` to update the context, and only `Nav` to use and re-render. I don't want to re-render the whole app on change.

Reading the React docs, I see Context users need to be downstream from the providers, so not sure this will be possible

Code (dramatically simplified):

```
 function NavBar () {
    const [itemsInCart, setItemsInCart] = useState(0)

    return (
      <button onClick={openCart}>{itemsInCart}</button>
    )
  }

 function Product() {

    function incrementCart () {
      ???
    }

    return (
      <button onClick={() => incrementCart}>add product to cart</button>
    )
  }

  function App () {
    return (
      <NavBar/>
      <Router>
        <Product/>
      </Router>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `useContext` to do it.

> A component calling useContext will always re-render when the context
> value changes. If re-rendering the component is expensive, you can
> optimize it by using memoization.

For example:

```
export const CartContext= React.createContext();

export const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [itemsInCart, setItemsInCart] = useState(null);

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider
      value={
        itemsInCart
      }
    >
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Then in some function you can use to get an update the cart:

```
  const {itemsInCart, setItemsInCart} = useContext(CartContext);
```

And lastly, update the Provider wrapping like:

```
  function App () {
    return (
     <CartProvider>
      <NavBar/>
      <Router>
        <Product/>
      </Router>
     </CartProvider>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Brilliant, works great, thank you!. Small update to expose the setter function to <Product/>, changed <CartProvider> to '<AddedCartCount.Provider value={[itemsInCart, setItemsInCart]}>' & 'const [itemsInCart, setItemsInCart] = useContext(CartContext)'